# create a UIViewController programmatically with Auto Layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I want to create a UIViewController that has a autolayout button. (same as in WWDC 2012 session 202) This view controller is pushed in a UINavigationController.

I do not want to use Story Boards at all. Everything must be done programmatically.

The question is how do I set the dimensions of the view controller's **main view** so that it has the size of the screen?

My view controller looks like this:

```c
@implementation EAViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    UIView * superview = self.view;
    UIButton * button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [button setTitle:@"Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [superview addSubview:button];

    NSLayoutConstraint * cn = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:button
                                                           attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                           relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                              toItem:self.view
                                                           attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                          multiplier:1.0
                                                            constant:0.0];

    [self.view addConstraint: cn];

    cn = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:button
                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                         toItem:self.view
                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                     multiplier:1.0
                                       constant:-20];

    [self.view addConstraint:cn];

    [self.view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [button setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

}

@end
```

And I push it like this in the App Delegate

```c
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // no story boards
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    EAViewController *viewController = [[EAViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
    navigationController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
}
```

The result is that the button does not have the correct Y offset. 
If I push directly the view controller without using the navigation controller, it works.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your y offset is off by the same amount as the navigation bar (48) because iOS 7 now goes fullscreen, i.e. up under the nav bar, so this is normal behaviour.